# np.fft.fft off by a factor of 1000 (fitting an powerspectrum)

Tags: numpy, fft

I'm trying to make a powerspectrum from an experimental dataset which I am reading in, and then to fit it to an theoretical curve. Now everything is working fine and I'm not getting errors, except for the fact that my curve keeps differing by a factor of 1000 from the data and I have absolutely no idea what the problem could be. I've asked a few people, but to no avail. (I hope that you guys will be able to help)

Anyways, I'm pretty sure that its not the units, as they were tripple checked by me and 2 others. Basically, I need to fit a powerspectrum to an equation by using the least squares method. 
I can't post the whole code, as its rather long and a bit messy, but this is the fourier part, I added comments to all arrays and vars which have not been declared in the code)

```
#Calculate stuff
Nm = 10**-6 #micro to meter
KbT = 4.10E-21 #Joule 
T = 297. #K
l = zvalue*Nm #meter

meany = np.mean(cleandatay*Nm) #meter (cleandata is the array that I read in from a cvs at the start.)
SDy = sum((cleandatay*Nm - meany)**2)/len(cleandatay) #meter^2

FmArray[0][i] = ((KbT*l)/SDy) #N
#print FmArray[0][i]

print float((i*100/len(filelist)))#how many % done?

#fourier
dt = cleant[1]-cleant[0] #timestep
N = len(cleandatay) #Same for cleant, its the corresponding time to cleandatay
```

Here is where the fourier part starts, I take the fft and turn it into a powerspectrum. Then I calculate the corresponding freq steps with the array freqs

```
fouriery =  np.fft.fft((cleandatay*(10**-6)))
fourierpower = (np.abs(fouriery))**2
fourierpower = fourierpower[1:N/2] #remove 0th datapoint and /2 (remove negative freqs)
fourierpower =  fourierpower*dt #*dt to account for steps

freqs = (1.+np.arange((N/2)-1.))/50.

#Least squares method
eta = 8.9E-4 #pa*s
Rbead = 0.5E-6#meter
constant = 2*KbT/(3*eta*pi*Rbead)    

omega = 2*pi*freqs #rad/s
Wcarray = 2.*pi*np.arange(0,30, 0.02003) #0.02 = 30/len(freqs)
ChiSq = np.zeros(len(Wcarray))

for k in range(0, len(Wcarray)):
    Py = (constant / (Wcarray[k]**2 + omega**2))
    ChiSq[k] = sum((fourierpower - Py)**2)
    pylab.loglog(omega, Py)
    print k*100/len(Wcarray) 


index = np.where(ChiSq == min(ChiSq))
cutoffw = Wcarray[index]    
Pygoed = (constant / (Wcarray[index]**2 + omega**2))
print cutoffw
print constant
print min(ChiSq)
pylab.loglog(omega,ChiSq)
```

So I have no idea what could be going wrong, I think its the fft, as nothing else can really go wrong. 
Below is the pic I get when I plot all the fit lines against the spectrum, as you can see it is off by about 1000 (actually exactly 1000, as this leaves a least square residue of 10^-22, but I can't just randomly multiply without knowing why)
[image: spectrum]
Just to elaborate on the picture. The green dots are the fft spectrum, the lines are the fits, the red dot is where it thinks the cutoff frequency is, and the blue line is the chi-squared fit, looking for the lowest value.

Comment: Try doing the analysis on a **known signal** that you generate in numpy, where you know exactly what the power spectrum should look like, say, a single simple sine wave, and see how that turns out.  (Also, this is much easier for people on this site to debug, since we can then run the code, assuming someone was so inclined.) Such examples are the unit tests of data analysis, and will give you justified confidence in you results.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation for the FFT that you are using.  Many FFTs introduce a scaling factor that is usually N * result (number of samples).  Multiplying by 1/N will scale the results back in line.  (You said that the result is 1000 too high....could it be that you are using a 1024 size FFT?)

Comment: I'm using the Cooley - Tukey algorithm (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html#numpy.fft.fft)

And I think that it accounts for that, however even if it didn't my array size is 5999, so thats not it. (Or is N something else here?)

Comment: Normally FFTs really want the size of the FFT to be a power of 2 (e.g. FFT size 4096)  Maybe the padding that is implied is having some impact.  Can you try a smaller or larger sample size and see if that affects the scaling?

Comment: Powers of two just make things faster, as long as your size is not a prime number Cooley-Tukey can still speed things up considerably. And SciPy/NumPy definitely does no padding unless asked to do so.

Comment: The key to dealing with any of the FFT libraries is to understand how they think about the world.  Some scale the results some don't some padd the input others don't.  RT*M is always a good place to start.

Comment: The exact definition for what Numpy's FFT computes is here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html#background-information

Answer (score 1):

Your library FFT routine might include a scale factor of 1/sqrt(n).

Check the documentation for the fft you used, as the proportion of the scale factor allocated between the fft and the ifft is arbitrary.

Comment: Numpy includes the whole 1/n factor in ifft.